# Process json data using Pyspark

Tags: python, json, pyspark, rdd

I am building a python script which will be executed through Apache spark in which I am generating a RDD from json file stored on S3 bucket.
I need to filter that json RDD according to some data in json document and thereby generating a new json file which consist of filtered json documents.That json file needs to be uploaded to S3 bucket.
So please suggest me appropriate solution for its implementation through [pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/python-programming-guide.html).

**Input json**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55a787ee9efccaeb288b457f"),
"data" : {
    "N◦ CATEGORIA" : 102.0, 
    "NOMBRE CATEGORIA" : "GASEOSAS", 
    "VARIABLE" : "TOP OF HEART", 
    "VAR." : "TOH", 
    "MARCA" : "COCA COLA ZERO", 
    "MES" : "ENERO", 
    "MES_N" : 1.0, 
    "AÑO" : 2014.0, 
    "UNIVERSO_TOTAL" : 1.0433982E7, 
    "UNIVERSO_FEMENINO" : 5529024.0, 
    "UNIVERSO_MASCULINO" : 4904958.0, 
    "PORCENTAJE_TOTAL" : 0.0066, 
    "PORCENTAJE_FEMENINO" : 0.0125, 
    "PORCENTAJE_MASCULINO" : null
}, 
"app_id" : ObjectId("5376349e11bc073138c33163"), 
"category" : "excel_RAC", 
"subcategory" : "RAC", 
"created_time" : NumberLong(1437042670), 
"instance_id" : null, 
"metric_date" : NumberLong(1437042670), 
"campaign_id" : ObjectId("5386602ba102b6cd4528ed93"), 
"datasource_id" : ObjectId("559f5c8f9efccacf0a3c9875"), 
"duplicate_id" : "695a3f5f562d0a02f1820fe5d91642a5"
}
```

The input json data needs to be filtered according to VARIABLE : "TOP OF HEART" and there by generate output json as following

**Output Json**

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("55b5d19e9efcca86118b45a2"), 
"widget_type" : "rac_toh_excel", 
"campaign_id" : ObjectId("558554b29efccab00a3c987c"), 
"datasource_id" : ObjectId("55b5d18f9efcca770b3c986a"), 
"date_time" : NumberLong(1388530800), 
"data" : {
    "key" : "COCA COLA ZERO", 
    "values" : {
        "x" : NumberLong(1388530800), 
        "y" : 1.0433982E7, 
        "data" : {
            "id" : ObjectId("553a151e5c93ffe0408b46f9"), 
            "month" : 1.0, 
            "year" : 2014.0, 
            "total" : 1.0433982E7, 
            "variable" : "TOH", 
            "total_percentage" : 0.0066
        }
    }
}, 
"filter" : [

]
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of the input and expected output?

Comment: @achampion Please note that the above question has mention of both sample input data and expected output data

Comment: I can't see how you generate the json output from the input, or what you mean by filtered based on "VARIABLE". This looks more like data transformation. Do you have a list of these records, filtering usually selects a subset of the data based on some criteria?